# bootstrap tooltip specific width for one tooltip

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

On a form I have an icon with a [bootstrap tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips).

The tooltip uses the standard CSS width of 150px used throughout the site.

I want to override the CSS width of this one tooltip from 150px to 400px, but also retain the 150px width for the other tooltips that appear in the test site.

How can I achieve this?

Here is my code HTML form code to add the icon and the tooltip to the icon:

```
$('#id_paragraph1_suggestion').after('<i id="id_icon_paragraph1_suggestion" class="fa fa-lightbulb-o blue_color icon_size18 no_decoration no_flicker_padding"></i>');

$("#id_icon_paragraph1_suggestion").tooltip({'html': true, 'title': 'Display suggestions to build your paragraph\n\nWe encourage you to mix & match different suggestions to complete your details.\n\nSimply replace the generic data with your own personalized information.'});
```

Here is my css code to set the width of the tooltips:

```
.tooltip-inner {
    max-width: 900px;
    white-space: pre-wrap
}
div[class="tooltip-inner"] {
    max-width: 150px
}
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this? so we can see how would it fix.

Comment: Just nutted this out. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, Here is the answer.

Add the following to the `.tooltip` attribute:

```
'template': '<div class="tooltip" role="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner tooltip-suggestion"></div></div>'
```

So, this is my changed (final) HTML code (changed from the OP):

```
$('#id_paragraph1_suggestion').after('<i id="id_icon_paragraph1_suggestion" class="fa fa-lightbulb-o blue_color icon_size18 no_decoration no_flicker_padding"></i>');

$("#id_icon_paragraph1_suggestion").tooltip({'template': '<div class="tooltip" role="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner tooltip-suggestion"></div></div>', 'html': true, 'title': 'Display suggestions to build your paragraph\n\nWe encourage you to mix & match different suggestions to complete your details.\n\nSimply replace the generic data with your own personalized information.'});
```

And this is the changed CSS code:

```
.tooltip-inner {
    max-width: 900px;
    white-space: pre-wrap
}
div[class="tooltip-inner"] {
    max-width: 150px
}
.tooltip-suggestion {
    max-width: 400px;
}
div[class="tooltip-suggestion"] {
    max-width: 400px
}
```

I hope that this will help someone.

I referenced this [link](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-tooltips.php) for the settings.

Answer (score 2):

While the template mechanism is the correct and documented way to do this, I find it cumbersome, and I still like to leave the Bootstrap 4 default of tooltips being added to the body (thus preventing using CSS nesting selectors to change selected tooltips), so I use the technique below.

```
// Event handler for tooltips being shown on someSelector items,
// and for those tooltips we add an inline style
$(someSelector).on('inserted.bs.tooltip', function() {
  $("body div.tooltip-inner").css("max-width", "750px");
});
```

That is, I listen to the "tooltip'ed" node, or some parent thereof, and catch events to say that tooltip has been added to the DOM triggered by them (or some child), and when I detect that's the case, I find the tooltip in the DOM and add an inline style to it.

This could be generalised to something like a "data-tooltip-class" attribute which the handler could then addClass() to the actual tooltip-inner but for my dynamically generated content the above works fine.